# Xcode 9/ Swift 4: Prevent UIButton from continuing to be highlighted, when you press it and drag the finger outside of its bounds

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, swift4, xcode9

When you press a UIButton, if you keep holding it while dragging your finger outside of its bounds, there's a certain distance that you can move you finger until the button's state is not "highlighted" anymore.

Essentially, you can press a button, move your finger outside of it, release it, and the button will still fire, even though your finger wasn't on it when it was released.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?  I want buttons to be "released" as soon as you're outside of them.

Comment: What button action have you added to the UIButton ?

Comment: You can bind Action UIControlEventTouchDragOutside of button and change the behavior whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `UIControlEvent` you are looking for is `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` - It works when touch is inside of the bound.

For more details check this URL:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents/uicontroleventtouchupinside?language=objc

Comment: How exactly would I go about disabling this event for all buttons in the application?

Comment: By default Control Events are disabled for the buttons. You have to add control event which you need.